# Symfony4 + Doctrine + League OAuth2 Server

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm attempting to setup an OAuth2 server/api using Symfony 4 and the [PHP League OAuth 2 Server](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com) library.

The problem I ran into was that the [interface](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/master/src/Entities/TokenInterface.php#L47) defined by the OAuth2Server library for the AccessToken requires a function that seems like it needs access to the database within the model (which is not how things are done with symfony/doctrine).

The interface requires that the AccessToken entity implement a setUserIdentifier method, but with Doctrine we do not set foreign id directly, instead we pass the model, e.g. `->setUser(User $user)`. (We can also use the EntityManger to create a reference to the foreign object, but again we would require access to the EM in the AccessToken entity).

My solution was to create an adapter, that I can pass both the EntityManager and AccessToken entity to, and then pass that to the OAuth2 library so that it can do what it needs to do.

Wondering if there is a better approach to this....

Comment: Did you get Symfony4 and League OAuth2 Server to work? I have to implement the same constellation ...

Comment: Same, curious how these ended up working together.